# When does $\sigma_{1}(p^{2k}) = q$ have a solution, where $p$ and $q$ are primes, and $k \geq 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma_{1}$ be the classical sum-of-divisors function.  For example, $\sigma(12)=1+2+3+4+6+12=28$.

Here is my question:

> When does $\sigma_{1}(p^{2k}) = q$ have a solution, where $p$ and $q$ are primes, and $k \geq 1$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

By a well-known formula for the sum of divisors of a prime power, we obtain
$$\sigma_{1}(p^{2k}) = \frac{p^{2k+1} - 1}{p - 1}.$$

If the equation $\sigma_{1}(p^{2k}) = q$ holds, then the integer
$$\frac{p^{2k+1} - 1}{p - 1}$$
is prime.

Since $2k+1$ is odd and $2k+1 \geq 3$, then
$$\sigma_{1}(p^{2k}) = \frac{p^{2k+1} - 1}{p - 1} \geq p^2 + p + 1.$$

Equality occurs when $k=1$.

Suppose $k=1$.  Then we are considering the equation
$$p^2+p+1=\sigma(p^2)=q.$$

If $q=2$, then $p(p+1)=1$.  A contradiction.  Therefore, $q \geq 3$.

If $p=2$, then $q=7$.  No contradiction.  So one possibility is $(k,p,q)=(1,2,7)$.

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $q=p^2+p+1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.  No contradiction.

If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $q=p^2+p+1 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  No contradiction.

If $p=3$, then $q=p^2+p+1=13$.  No contradiction.  So another possibility is $(k,p,q)=(1,3,13)$.

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then $q=p^2+p+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, which implies that $q=3$.  Therefore, $p(p+1)=2$.  This contradicts $p \geq 2$.  Therefore, $p \not\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

If $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then $q=p^2+p+1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  No contradiction.

Alas, this is as far as I could go, with my elementary congruence methods.  And I have only been able to consider the case $k=1$!

**Added September 24 2016** Note that we necessarily have $p \neq q$, because otherwise $p^2 + 1 = 0$, which is a contradiction.  Suppose further that $q < p$.  Then we have $p^2 + p + 1 = q < p$, which implies $p^2 + 1 < 0$, again a contradiction.  Therefore, we must have $p < q$. This holds even for $k \neq 1$.

(I put the tag **diophantine-equations** because I could not find an **exponential-equations** tag.  Please feel free to remove this tag if it is not suitable for this post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $2k+1 = ab$, then $p^{2k+1}-1 = (p^a)^b - 1$ is divisible by $p^a-1$ and $p^b-1$.  Thus a necessary condition is that $2k+1$ is prime.

The case $p=2$ gives you the Mersenne primes.

See e.g. [OEIS sequence A028491](https://oeis.org/A028491) ($n$ such that $(3^n-1)/2$ is prime) and the links and references there.